# Are there any internally consistent variants of Feng Shui?

Tags: metaphysics, eastern-philosophy

There's a [videogame](https://www.gog.com/en/game/amazing_cultivation_simulator) that includes Feng Shui as a game mechanic. I'm trying to create a mod that improves that aspect using computational fluid dynamics. The programming side of this should be simple, as there are a seemingly endless number of algorithms available. However, all of these need a well-defined set of laws in order to create the simulation.

There are plenty of blog posts about Feng Shui, but I was unable to find any single source that had a set of rules detailed enough to simulate. Piecing together rules from multiple sources, however, resulted in contradictions. The main issue was in how dead ends are treated. Some sources claim that living in a cul-de-sac is bad because the qi will stagnate without an outflow. Others say that a living space with multiple doors is bad since it allows the qi to leak out.

A quick search shows that there are dozens of Feng Shui branches that have developed over time. Are there any that:

- have well-defined and internally consistent sets of rules
- have names that can be found with a web search
- use the five elements, as this is a core element to the videogame
- explain why a south-facing bedroom might be more desirable than a north-facing bedroom

Comment: I’m struggling to see any philosophical aspect to this question

Comment: @Frog I'm not posing a philosophical question; I'm asking for help identifying schools of philosophy. Is there a different board this should be posted on?

Comment: this community is specifically for philosophy questions, but it seems relatively unusual for questions to be closed as off-topic.  I’ve no idea where feng shui belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be any one particular branch of Feng Shui that has all of the features you are looking for. However, the Ba Gua school of Feng Shui comes close.

The Ba Gua is a grid that is used to map out a space. It consists of eight trigrams, each representing a different aspect of life. These trigrams are then arranged into a bagua, or eight-sided figure. The Ba Gua is used to determine the flow of energy, or qi, in a space.

The Ba Gua school of Feng Shui has a well-defined set of rules that are based on the five elements: wood, fire, earth, metal, and water. This school also explains why a south-facing bedroom might be more desirable than a north-facing bedroom. The reason is that the south is associated with the element of fire, which is considered to be a Yang, or positive, energy. North is associated with the element of water, which is considered to be a Yin, or negative, energy. Therefore, a south-facing bedroom would have more Yang energy, which is considered to be more positive.